# When running recipes without modifying the build can you define multiple recipes in the rewriye.yml file?

Tags: openrewrite

So I am looking at how to run recipes without modifying the build as defined here and here
There is no mention of how to run multiple recipes at once. Can I define a rewrite.yml file that contains multiple recipes and then run it using a single command?

I'm not sure how I can define multiple recipes to all be run once after another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `rewrite.yml` file at the root of your project and add multiple recipes to the `recipeList`, as described here:
https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/yaml-format-reference#where-openrewrite-yaml-files-can-exist